# rowmean and standard deviation using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(500 * 10), nrow = 500, ncol = 10)
x[, 1] <- 1:500

x <- data.frame(x)
names(x) <- c('ID', 2000:2008)      

library(data.table)
setDT(x)
```

I want to calculate mean, sd and no. of data points per row but I am getting error

```
x[, c("meanY",'sdY',"nY") := .(rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), sd(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), rowSums(!is.na(.SD))), .SDcols=c(2:10)]
```

Comment: There's no `sd` method for `data.table|frame`s. try `sd(iris, na.rm=TRUE)` you'll get the same error. What do you want there, exactly?

Comment: I need for each row, the mean, standard deviation and number of datapoints. My original data has NAs in some rows that is why I used the na.rm = T as well.

Comment: How about `x[, c("meanY",'sdY',"nY") := .(rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), sd(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), rowSums(!is.na(.SD))), .SDcols=c(2:10), by=ID]` ?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I'm not sure what you mean by `There is no sd method for data.table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues lies in `sd()` which doesn't work row-wise.

```
x[,
  c("meanY",'sdY',"nY") := 
    .(rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), 
      apply(.SD, 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE), 
      rowSums(!is.na(.SD))), 
  .SDcols = 2:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output as a list, you can use following code to have a try:

```
op <- c("mean","sd","length")
r <- lapply(op, function(v) apply(x, 1, eval(parse(text = v))))
names(r) <- op
```

where it should work with your `data.frame` example:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(500 * 10), nrow = 500, ncol = 10)
x[, 1] <- 1:500
x <- data.frame(x)
names(x) <- c('ID', 2000:2008)
```